# MOSTRAR APROBADOS Y DESAPROBADOS EN UN TABLA SQL

Tags: microsoft-sql

Tengo este código en sql para mostrar una tabla con notas de un curso. Además de todo lo mostrado, debe haber una columna "Mensaje" donde por cada fila diga si el alumno aprobó o desaprobó dependiendo del promedio. Adjunte una imágen de como se ve la tabla; sin embargo, no se como hacer que aparezca aprobado o desaprobado. Agradecería mucho si me podrían ayudar, gracias :)

```
select A.IdAlumno,A.NomAlumno,A.ApeAlumno,N.ExaParcial,N.ExaFinal,SUM(EXAPARCIAL+EXAFINAL)/2 PROMEDIO,'APROBADO' MENSAJE 
from alumno A 
join notas N on a.IdAlumno=n.IdAlumno 
join curso C on c.IdCurso=n.Idcurso 
where C.IdCurso like 'C001' 
group by A.IdAlumno,A.NomAlumno,A.ApeAlumno,N.ExaParcial,N.ExaFinal;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado CASE ... WHEN? Un saludo

Comment: Con un IF, podrías resolverlo. IF ( (ExFinal + ExaParcial)/2 > 5, 'APROBADO', 'SUSPENSO')

Comment: Ya lo pude realizar, muchas gracias!

Comment: hola, puedes publicar la respuesta, para mi puede usa una condicional ternaria.